# LaTeX commands for number sets with and without zero

Tags: number

Can somebody tell me the LatTeX commands for number sets with and without zero? All I'm able to find are the commands for the general sets (\mathbb{N} and so on...).
Thank you! I'm talking about these Symbols:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What exactly do you mean by number sets with and without zero? Something like `$\mathbb{N}^+$`?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome and thank you for the help! $\mathbb{N}^+$ does exactly what I want. Do you by any chance also know how to add the Zero in the bottom right corner of a Set symbol? (As depicted above)

Comment: `$\mathbb{N}^{+}_{0}$`...braces are optional if the super/sub-script is a single token.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just I add an easy example using also `\mid` or the classic `|` with or without `braket` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{braket}


\begin{document}
This is an example $\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}=\Set{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R},x\geq 0}$ using \verb|braket| package.

\[\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}=\Set{x|x\in\mathbb{R},x\geq 0}\]
Without the use of \verb|braket| package:
$\mathbb{R}^{-}_{0}=\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R},x\leq 0\}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{-}_{0}=\{x| x\in\mathbb{R},x\leq 0\}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Mantis I'm glad to help you. All the best.